# I am confused on principle of acknowledgment

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

version:2.1.11

question:
i have some wrong parameter configuration:
max.poll.records:500
max.poll.interval.ms:10000.
but consume takes about 25000s. so it will thorws exception:
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.

then i corrected the parameter， so this error is solved.

however, I am confused, i have committed by ack.acknowledge() when consumed one message.
why the offset can't be committed at all?
this is code

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic}")
public void consume(ConsumerRecord<String, SyncResMessage> record, Acknowledgment ack) {
    
    try {
        // consume message
        consumerService.dealResource(record.value());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("error when consume data, data key is {}, exception is {}.", record.key(), e);
    }

    if (ack != null) {
        LOGGER.info("commit successfully.");
        ack.acknowledge();
    } else {
        LOGGER.error("message of commit is null, record is {}.", JsonUtil.toString(record));
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated～

Answer (score 2):

maybe this is answer.
MANUAL means not commit immediatlly, it will update this map.
MANUAL_IMMEDIATE means commit immediatlly.

Comment: That is correct. With MANUAL, the commits are queued and applied after the batch is processed.